# MariaDB mysqlslap not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When i execute the sample provided (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqlslap/#examples), it fails with the following error. Any idea why ?

```
mysql> mysqlslap 
    ->  --delimiter=";" 
    ->  --create="CREATE TABLE t (a int);INSERT INTO t VALUES (5)"
    ->  --query="SELECT * FROM t"
    ->  --concurrency=40
    ->  --iterations=100
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqlslap 
 --delimiter=";" 
 --create="CREATE TABLE t (a int);INSERT INTO t VAL' at line 1
```

Comment: I do not think you should launch this utility within the command line client. This is an external application to be run from the command line (but not from the client).

Comment: @Shadow you can put it as answer. Its a command line tool. Not a sql command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by you trying to run the `mysqlslap` **command line** tool within mariadb's (MySQL's) own command line client. Run `mysqlslap` directly from the command line instead.